# Stash a specific hunk, Git

Tags: git

Using Git, I want to stash only one hunk in one specific file in order to commit the rest of the changes. Therefore, I could go back to my temporary change by pulling it from stash.
However, the only way I could find is to stash the whole unstaged files.

Comment: What about adding everything to the index except that hunk (using `--patch`), and then `git stash save --keep-index`?

Comment: You can simply commit first, and then stash.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've tried this and what it does is stashing staged files (while keeping them staged too) and removing all the non staged modifications. This not the behaviour I was looking for

Comment: That's why I recommended adding everything. It can all be unstaged after the stash.

Comment: Could you please show how did you use --patch ?

Comment: It’s interactive. I would add all but that one file to the stage and then use `git add —patch` on the last file to stage all hunks except the hunk I want to stash. Then stash keeping the index which will stash the hunk but leave the stage alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In recent Git versions, the `git stash push` command accepts a pathspec to specify which file(s) to stash, and a `-p` option like `git add`:

```
git stash push -p -- filename(s)
```

or

```
git stash -p -- filename(s)
```

This will give you a prompt similar to `git add -p` to chose the hunk(s) you want to stash, and it will only stash the changes you selected for the files your specified.

The solution above was tested with git 2.17.0. I also tested with an older version, git 2.4.10, and the pathspec was not supported. But the `-p` was still available for `git stash save`:

```
git stash save -p
```

or

```
git stash -p
```

It's not as nice as the option with more recent Git, though, because you have to interactively go through all the files, not just the one you want.

Comment: PS: just tested on git 2.4, and filespec is not supported, but `git stash save -p` works, only it makes you go through all the files instead of only the specified one.

Comment: Awesome ! This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem. Now that I found it - thanks for asking the question! - I think I'll use it too.

Comment: Simpler than my suggestion!

Comment: Another approach is to stage the changes you want to stash first, then run git stash --staged.  This allows you to select the hunks first, and compose the comment/message later, instead of having to do both in one step.

Comment: @XiangmingHu That's a good suggestion, especially since it means you could stage files in multiple calls to `git add` or `git add -p` and only stash when you were happy with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workflow that accomplishes what you want using a branch, which is personally what I prefer to use instead of the stash. It's more typing and more commands, but it gives you full control of the results afterwards.

```
git checkout -b dev.temp
git add <file-to-stash>
git commit -m'stash work alike'
git checkout <base-branch>
# commit what you need in <base-branch>
```

From here you have your "stashed" file in a branch so there are many ways to continue.

Option 1: go the the branch and keep working there, with a merge or rebase when you're done:

```
git checkout dev.temp
git rebase <base-branch>
#work here, merge or rebase when you're done
```

Option 2: check out the file into your main branch:

```
git checkout dev.temp <file-to-stash>
```

`<file-to-stash>` is now in the index; use `git reset` to revert it to a locally changed file and keep working where you were at.

Option 3: cherry pick the commit so it's also committed in your working branch - this is the least like your workflow, however, since it leaves `<file-to-stash>` committed in `, but here it is for completeness:

```
git cherry-pick dev.temp
```

With all options, you can delete the branch with `git branch -D dev.temp` when you're done with it. `-d` will do if you actually merged it back in, but `-D` is needed if the branch is not actually merged but you have recovered the changes you wanted.

I have a strong preference for using temporary dev branches over the stash because it gives you a lot more control over what you put in and how you take it back out afterwards, although I agree there are also effective (and certainly quicker) workflows with the stash itself: it's a trade-off between speed and control.

Comment: I believe this could be a workaround to save temporary changes. But, I was looking for a quick usage of the stash itself on a specific hunk, without making temporary commits

Comment: I agree, a quick stash command would be nicer, and I just found one. I'll write a second answer.